# Why weblogic create new session each time when I refresh page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, weblogic-10.x

In my jsp page I have code

```
<%
    System.out.println("_--------------_-");
    System.out.println(session);
%>
```

my web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Онлайн библиотека. Лаб. р.3 </display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>resources/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>sumy.javacourse.library.controller.Main</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>sumy.javacourse.library.controller.LibServerException</exception-type>
        <location>/jsp/server_error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

When I refreshing page I always receive a new session. Please tell me what I am doing wrong?
P.S. When I run it in jetty all is good. I always receive the same session.

[image: Jetty output]

[image: Weblogic]

I change my jsp to:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Session ID: <%=session.getId()%>
    <br />
    <a href="?t=<%=new java.util.Date().getTime()%>">click me</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I clicked to link in Jetty i receive the same session id.
In weblogic - different.

Comment: How do you confirm that a session is created on every page refresh? Besides, the session timeout is set to 30. Consequently, the session will expire, If you exceed that limit. In case, you might be overlooking the timeout period.

Comment: @Tiny I added some screans. It shows output in jetty and in weblogic. I think that I am not run out of time that written in web.xml.

Comment: What problem is this causing? It might help to know what happens/what errors you see because of this behavior

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing I can't received attributte set by session. When page refreshing session is always new and attribute is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution: I used chrome and it not works, when I try it in firefox all is good ;) In chrome you must clear your cache.
Maybe it stupid, but I spend all day to this problem, maybe someone find it usefull.

Comment: You saved my life! The same for me. Spent hours of figuring out why I can't get to the next page.:-)